# Proof verification: Let $a$ be an irrational number and $r$ be a nonzero rational number. If $s$ is a rational number then $ar$ + $s$ is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I have to prove the following:

> Prove: Let $a$ be an irrational number and $r$ be a nonzero rational number. If $s$ is a rational number then $ar$ + $s$ is irrational

So, I decided to do a proof by contradiction and I was wondering if someone can check it for me?

**Proof by contradiction**

Suppose $ar + s$ is rational then it can be expressed a ratio of integers, $\frac{p}{q}$. This implies

\begin{align}
ar + s &= \frac{p}{q} \\
ar &= \frac{p}{q} - s \\
ar &= \frac{p-s}{q} \quad (*) \\
\end{align}

Contradiction $(*)$. We know that an irrational times a rational is irrational and therefore, it can't be expressed as a ratio of integers but here we are claiming that it can be expressed as such. Therefore, our original statement must be false. Therefore, $ar+s$ must be irrational. $QED$

Does this make sense?

Thanks!

Below is the proof rewritten for completeness.

**Proof by contradiction**
Suppose $ar + s$ is rational then it can be expressed a ratio of integers, $\frac{p}{q}$. This implies

\begin{align}
ar + s &= \frac{p}{q} \\
ar &= \frac{p}{q} - s \\
ar &= \frac{p-sq}{q}  \\
a &= \frac{p-sq}{rq} \quad (*)
\end{align}

**Contradiction** $(*)$. We know that $a$ is irrational which implies that it cannot be written as a ratio of integers, in other words $a = \frac{p-sq}{rq} \in \mathbb{Q}$ which is false. Therefore, our original statement must be false also. Therefore, $ar + s$ is irrational. $QED$.

Comment: Why not add the last and really punch line?: $$ar=\frac{p-s}q\implies a=\frac{p-s}{rq}\in\Bbb Q\;\ldots\text{contradiction}$$

Comment: You should include the condition : where $p$ and $q$ have no common factors other than 1

Comment: @Shubham: Why bother?

Comment: @Shubham That isn't used in the proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty good.  You have an error on the starred line ($s$ should be multiplied by $q$) and you will also want to divide the equation by $r$ to make the conclusion explicit.

Comment: Ha! What a stupid/silly mistake on $(*)$. Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: After edits looks perfect now.