# Is irrational times rational always irrational?

Tags: real-analysis

Is an irrational number times a rational number always irrational?

If the rational number is zero, then the result will be rational. So can we conclude that in general, we can't decide, and it depends on the rational number?

Comment: If $q\ne0$ is rational and $x$ is irrational then $qx$ is irrational. Is this your question?

Comment: Hey, zero is the only one that breaks the rule :)

Comment: why people are down voting?

Comment: Well the idea falls apart very quickly, if $x$ is irrational, $x^{-1}$ is irrational too.

Comment: It depends on whether you can decide if the rational number is zero.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove that the product of a rational and irrational number is irrational](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/45104/121411); see also [Proof verification: Let _a_ be an irrational number and _r_ be a nonzero rational number…](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/746665/121411)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Any nonzero rational number times an irrational number is irrational. Let $r$ be nonzero and rational and $x$ be irrational. If $rx=q$ and $q$ is rational, then $x=q/r$, which is rational. This is a contradiction.

Comment: great answer, Matt. How about $irratonat^{annother irrational}$?

Comment: No. The classic argument is that if ${\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2}$ isn't a counterexample, then $2 = ({\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2})^{\sqrt 2} = {\sqrt 2}^2$ must be. It's much harder to show, but apparently ${\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2}$ *is* irrational.

Comment: @mattsamuel Does this assume an irrational times one is irrational? Should this also be proved, or is it just assumed?

Comment: @Rasmus It is not assumed, but it is practically tautological. $1x=x$ for all $x$, so if $x$ has property $P$ then so does $1x$.

Answer (score 15):

If $a$ is irrational and $b\ne0$ is rational, then $a\,b$ is irrational. Proof: if $a\,b$ were equal to a rational $r$, then we would have $a=r/b$ rational.

Answer (score 9):

**Claim:** If $x$ is irrational and $r \ne 0$ is rational, then $xr$ is irrational.

**Proof:** Suppose that $xr$ were rational.  Then, $x = \frac{xr}{r}$ would be rational (as the quotient of two rationals).  This clearly contradicts the assumption that $x$ is irrational.  Therefore, $xr$ is irrational.

The $r = 0$ case is special, and the above argument doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Irrational times non-zero rational is irrational number.
If not, suppose a is a irrational number and b is non-zero rational number such that ab=c, where c is a rational number.As collection of all rational number forms field.so any non-zero rational is invertible.So that would imply a is rational number--which is not true.