# Proof that, for every positive integer $n$, $\log_7(n)$ is either integer or irrational

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

> For every positive integer $n$, $\log_7(n)$ is either integer or irrational.

I have seen different kinds of proof for this statement, this was my approach kindly verify if I am correct.

$\text{Proof - } \text{ This proof is by contradiction.}$

$\text{Let $log_7(n)$ be rational number which is not an integer.}$

Which is the same thing as saying,

$$log_7(n) = p/q$$

$\text{Where $p,q$ don't have common divisor and $q>1$}$

$\begin{align*}
log_7(n) = p/q &\Rightarrow n = 7^{p/q} \\
&\Rightarrow n = 7^p \cdot 7^{1/q} \\
&\Rightarrow (7^p \in \mathbb{Z}) \wedge (7^{1/q} \text{ is irrational}) 
\end{align*}$

as $7^p$ is a product of integers it is an integer and $\forall(q>1) 7^{1/q}$ is irrational, I have proved it but did not include it to keep this question short.

[Is irrational times rational always irrational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009570/is-irrational-times-rational-always-irrational)

> Theorm. Any nonzero rational number times an irrational number is
>   irrational.
>
> Proof - Let $r$ be nonzero and rational and x irrational. If $rx=q$
>   and $q$ is rational, then $x=q/r$, which is rational. This is a
>   contradiction.

It follows from this that $n$ is an irrational number which is a contradiction as we started with n as integer, hence $log_7(n)$ must be irrational or Integer.

Is this proof sound? I think so my conclusion is not sound enough to conclude that $log_7(n)$ is irrational or Integer. I think so I am not contradicting the assumption; which is what we must do in proof by contradiction?

Comment: The first (huge) problem in all this is that $$7^{p/q}\ne7^p\cdot7^{1/q}$$

Comment: Silly mistake! Sorry!