# the product of a constructible number and a non-constructible number is constructible or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Well, for example:
I know that $\sqrt{7}$ is a constructible number. Also $\sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{2}\scriptstyle 3]{2}$ is not a constructible number.

My question is that the product of $\sqrt{7}$ and $\sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{2}\scriptstyle 3]{2}$ denotes as $\sqrt{7} \cdot \sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{2}\scriptstyle 3]{2}$ a constructible number or not ?

My guess is $\sqrt{7} \cdot \sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{2}\scriptstyle 3]{2}$ is not a constructible but I am not sure if my guess is correct

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009570/is-irrational-times-rational-always-irrational (replace "rational" with "constructible").

Comment: If $ab$ is constructible  and $a$ is constructible  then $b=\frac{ab}{a}$ is constructible

Comment: $0$ is constructible ...